# AJAX not working in Laravel 5.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I've created a simple HTML doc with a JS file to test an AJAX call and I know the XHR request is being submitted successfully but the response has nothing in it. In the console I see that the `template` attribute has nothing associated with it in the `post` request to the server but I can't figure out why...

Master HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{!! asset('/js/main.js') !!}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')   
</body>
</html>
```

Page HTML:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<p>Make a new email to send out:</p>

{!! Form::token() !!}

<textarea id='template' style="resize:none;width:500px;height:100px;"></textarea>

<button id='addContacts'>Add Contacts</button>

<span id='loading' style='display:none;'>Loading...</span>

<div id='results'></div>

@endsection
```

JS file (tried both `type` and `method` in the request but I'm using JQuery 2.1.3 so both will work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// return the list of input fields for this template
$('#addContacts').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://newco.dev/addContacts',
        data: 
        {
            'template' : $('#template').val(),
            '_token' : $('input[name=_token]').val()
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('Something went wrong.');
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#results').html(response);
        }
    });
});

}); // end doc ready
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/addContacts', 'ActionController@returnFields');
```

Controller (yes, `use App\Http\Requests;` is included):

```
public function returnFields(Request $request)
{
    sleep(2);
    return $request->template;
}
```

When submitted, the `#loading` div is shown for 2 seconds as expected, but then nothing is returned...

In the dev tools (in Chrome) after the button is clicked:

```
Remote Address:192.168.10.10:80
Request URL:http://newco.dev/addContacts
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

FORM DATA:
template:
_token:AuOTiLSg3rKYtLDIH1abzsQHsLv0fzswgXIfzE8h
```

Nothing is recorded in the Laravel logs; I'm assuming because it's not a `500` error.

Any ideas? I use Laravel every day as an API developer so I'm very familiar with its concepts but I'm not the best JS developer (although I definitely have experience with it) so maybe I'm just missing something obvious. If you need anymore data, just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: You got any error in console ?

Comment: Nothing... Only the success message in the Network tab from the response shown in the question. Nothing in the Console tab or in the console itself. When I call on the elements in the DOM from the console, they're returned correctly which is even more confusing.

Comment: In your controller , you're making just to sleep and return $template.. What is the purpose of it ?

Comment: The sleep is to test if the beforeSend is working (was the request successfully sent, in other words) and the returned string is again just for testing.

Comment: Then, may i know what you expect the framework to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying a million things and talking to a ton of people, I changed the name of the attribute in the page to `email` instead of `template` and everything works beautifully. I'm not sure why the word "template" would cause an issue but it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should `show` your div that you hide

i.e., Change `$('#loading').hide();` to `$('#loading').show();`

Then only you can able to see the output that you got

```
success: function(response) {
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#results').html(response);
        }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: The `#loading` div is only to show that the AJAX call is connecting to the server successfully... It doesn't get any data passed into it. `#results` is always visible which is where the `response` is being inserted.